# What is the Shaḥaf according to Ḥizquni?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, kashrut-kosher, commentaries, non-kosher-species, birds

The שחף (*Shaḥaf*) is a bird forbidden by the Torah in both *Sefer Wayiqra* and *Devarim*.

Ḥizquni (חזקוני, Rabbi Ḥizqiyah ben Manoaḥ), writing in Old French, states ([Wayiqra 11:16](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/tanach/parshanut/chizkuni/3.pdf)):

> אשפמר"א ויש אומרים: מוייסו"ן מוליד שחפת

Based on [an online Anglo-Norman dictionary](http://www.anglo-norman.net/dict/AND-201-4920E8AD-3E6B4932-50EEA220-E0B51A9C), it appears *moisson* is sparrow in English.

Is that right? What about *aspamra* (if that is indeed the proper *niqqud*)?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/92488/2091

Comment: @DannySchoemann That was a typo on my part. Fixed. Why do you suspect it's *espaigné*?

Comment: @DannySchoemann The definition glosses the words *ung egle espany* as *an eagle displayed*. *Espaigné* is "displayed," not an eagle

Comment: I wonder whether אשפמר״א may derive from Latin _parra_.

Comment: Perhaps the osprey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://tablet.otzar.org/pages/?&restore=1&t=1587320370333&pagenum=42&book=10082) edition of Chizkuni says it means אישפו"ט which means [נקר](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A0%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D), which is a woodpecker.

Comment: Thanks for the source! How do you know אישפו"ט means נקר?

Comment: @Lee That's what it says in the edition. You can click the link and see.